# Using Trident to read from RDBMS

Tags: java, apache-storm, trident

I am new to Storm and Trident. I wrote a spout (used Storm core) to read from RDBMS. I override the `open()` method of `BaseRichSpout`

```
public void open(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, SpoutOutputCollector spoutOutputCollector) {
    this.collector = spoutOutputCollector;
    this.context = topologyContext;
    // connect to DB
    connection = RDBMSConnection.getConnection();
    query = "SELECT * from CUSTOMER";

}
```

Now I wanted to use Trident to do the same since it has built in join function. Could anyone please let me know, how can we achieve the same functionality in Trident. I am planning to implement `IOpaquePartitionedTridentSpout`. Also is there any tutorial to learn more about Trident.

Comment: you may check trident mongodb as a reference for your work from here: https://github.com/eldenbishop/trident-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to reinvent the wheel for such a common task and see if one of the existing solutions works for you. For example: https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-jdbc

You could always use it as a reference for your own implementation.

Comment: This lib don't have a spout implementation.